# Intel graphic incompatibility issue

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics

I'm having a problem with my graphics.

Everything was fine when I had Windows 8 installed in my laptop. Ever since I upgraded to Windows 8.1, my graphics card is always crashing (media player, browser, etc.). When I shutdown my computer, it ends with a black screen for 10 minutes and then reboots.

I contacted Microsoft, Intel, and HP (my manufacturer) but none of them helped me. It seems that there are no drivers to Windows 8.1 for my laptop. Is there any way to solve this or make it work? Any idea?

- Mobile Intel(R) 945 Express Chipset Family (Microsoft Corporation - WDDM 1.0)
- Win 8.1 Pro
- 32-bit
- HP 530 Notebook PC

Comment: You can try the generic display drivers, I am shocked, you didn't have this problem while using Windows 8.0 because WDDM 1.0 is the wrong version even for Windows 8.0

Comment: I tryed a lot of things including uninstall this version and install a previous version of drivers but nothing works. I just don't understand the reason why the drivers worked in win8 and don't work in win8.1. At least I had no crashes and problems like that.

Comment: go to intel website and run update. it should download latest correct driver.

Comment: @sharif I did that already. There are no drivers. I'm looking for any other way to solve that.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what your graphics card is, but as far as I know the HP 530 was only sold with integrated graphics--specifically **Intel GMA 950**.

[Microsoft provides drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn344644.aspx) for this graphics device for Windows 8.1, but it's not bundled with Windows, instead they are available from Windows Update.

HP even provides an article for this, [Updating Drivers and Software with Windows Update (Windows 8)](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&docname=c03330139).  Take note of step 4: **Optional updates**.

Comment: Thanks @Jason , it looks like Microsoft has some drivers now. I downloaded them but they are in CAB format. How can I install them and where?

Comment: I installed the packages but media player is still crashing and everything related with video :/